# Status of narrations that come from Al-A'mash through Minhal ibn Amr

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

Salam Guys,

I would request my readers to not to mark this question as duplicate. This question is a bit different from the [previous question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61209/what-is-the-status-of-narrator-minhal-ibn-amr-did-scholars-really-rejected-his) I asked about narrator Minhal Ibn Amr.

My question is about particular narrations that come from Al-A'mash through Minhal Ibn Amr.

According to [THIS](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46316/did-prophet-isa-go-to-the-cross/46325#46325) source it has been stated that both Yahya ibn Ma'īn and Adh-Dhahabi had reasons to weaken narrations that came from Al-A'mash through Al-Minhāl ibn 'Amr.

**The problem here is that the user III-AK-III who posted his answer did not cite any reference in order to prove that Yahya bin Ma'in and Ad-Dhahabi actually weakened the narrations that come from Al-A'mash through Minhal Ibn Amr.**

Al-A'mash and Minhal were Kufi and met each other. Both of them have also narrated narrations in Bukhari.

**The main question is: where is the evidence that suggests that Yahyah bin Ma'in and Ad-Dhahabi weakened the narration that come from Al-A'mash through Minhal Ibn Amr?**

Comment: I'm not certain, but I only know of one book of Yahya ibn Ma'in on 'ilm ar-Rijal however it has different (at least three known) versions that's why sometimes two different opinions of him might be suggested or quoted. As for a-Dhahabi one should check some of his later works, as with the time he became more conservative as for example when he wrote his summary of al-Hakim's al-Mustdrak.

Comment: Actually I'd have a quote from al-Mizzi's Tahdeeb al-Kamal see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/3722/15582) where he quotes ibn Ma'in somehow this was easier to locate as that in Tarikh ibn Mai'yn (maybe ad-Duri didin't quote that in his version or I've overseen it). Later al-Mizzi also quoted imam Muslim's position about al-Minhal ibn 'Amr.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - "Later al-Mizzi also quoted imam Muslim's position about al-Minhal ibn 'Amr" So, what is the position of Imam Muslim about Minhal Ibn Amr?